# Pass route parameter to controller in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using passport JS to authenticate my user account. Passing the passport variable from app.js to routes.js and controller.js. When I pass between routes.js and controller.js, I have no idea how to implement. I tried different approaches but didn't work. My first priority was stored all the implementation codes inside controller instead of routes.

**App.js**

```
var userRouter = require('./api/routes/userRoutes.js')(app,passport);
```

**Routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app,passport){
  var UserRouter = express.Router();
  users = require('./../controllers/UserController')
  UserRouter.post('/users', users.authenticate);
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next){
    // How do I get passport variable here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is the best way in this case, but like an option you can try this:

In App.js:

```
global. passport = passport;
var userRouter = require('./api/routes/userRoutes.js')(app, passport);
```

In Controller.js:

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(global.passport);
}
```